# ¿Como pasar un dato seleccionado a una api y llenar otro select con el resultado?

Tags: typescript, angular7

Hola soy nuevo en angular
Tengo el siguiente formulario Html en angular:

```
<form >
            <div class="form-group mt-5" >
                <h3 class="heading1">MONEDA</h3>
                <select  name="monedas" class="form-select" [(ngModel)]= "monedasSelect">
                    <option [value]="moneda.codigo" *ngFor= "let moneda of MONEDAS">{{moneda.nombre}}</option>  
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group mt-5">
                <h3 class="heading1">CRIPTOMONEDA</h3>
                <select name="criptomonedas" class="form-select">
                    <option value="" >Seleccionar</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-5">
                <button  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">COTIZAR</button>
            </div>  
        </form>
```

El primer select lo lleno con el siguiente combo .ts:

```
MONEDAS = [
    { codigo: '', nombre: 'Seleccionar' },
    { codigo: 'USD', nombre: 'Dolar de Estados Unidos' },
    { codigo: 'MXN', nombre: 'Peso Mexicano' },
    { codigo: 'EUR', nombre: 'Euro' },
    { codigo: 'GBP', nombre: 'Libra Esterlina' }
    ];
```

Necesito enviar lo que esta seleccionado en el primero como parametro a una api y llenar el segundo.
tengo este servicio:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CryptoService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

   }

   getApi(){
    const url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/mktcapfull?limit=10&tsym=USD';

    return this.http.get(url);
   }

   
}
```

Pero no se como hacerlo, necesito ayuda.